# Edge + Webdriver 17134 - extension are not loaded

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I posted a issue in edge bug site(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19450391/). Posting here as well to know if there are any workaround for this or if this is an usage issue.

I am using selenium using typescript for automating an edge extension. Sample script and extension is in the bug link above (one of the upload has missing end }).

```
let options = new Options();

let cap = new Capabilities({
    specialFolders: process.env.LOCALAPPDATA+'\\Packages\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\Extensions'
});

let service = new ServiceBuilder(process.env.USERPROFILE + '\\Downloads\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
                    .setPort(17556);

const prefs = new logging.Preferences();
prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);
let driver = new Builder()
.withCapabilities(cap)
.setLoggingPrefs(prefs)
.forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge')
.setEdgeOptions(options)
.setEdgeService(service)
.build();
```

Edge browser gets launched, but its not loading any extension from the special folder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages#automated-testing-with-webdriver).

Comment: looks like i got the parameter wrong changing the capability to 
`let cap = new Capabilities({
        extensionPaths: [
            process.env.LOCALAPPDATA+'\\Packages\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\Extensions\\my_extension'
        ]
    });`
worked

Comment: I can see that you solved the issue. It is better if you post the code as a solution and mark it as an answer. It can help other community members who will have similar issue like yours.